# How to perform a 2D-multi-peak fitting?

Tags: fitting, data, peak-detection

I am wondering how to decompose the data[x,y] into several elliptic-shaped functions,
i.e. $f[x,y]=\frac{H}{(1+(\frac{x-x1}{a1})^2+(\frac{y-y1}{b1})^2)^{3/2}}$.

I could follow in 1D case, decomposition data[x] into $\frac{H}{1+((x-x1)/a1)^2}$, by just following (with modification)
[How to perform a multi-peak fitting?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26336/how-to-perform-a-multi-peak-fitting)
, but I cannot perform in 2D case.

Does anyone have a good idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Possibly helpful? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/207812/finding-a-parametric-curve-fitting-a-two-dimensional-dataset

Comment: @MelaGo Thank you for helping me. But actually the data is three dimension in graph, and even determining the number of basis functions is not trivial.